# OpenRewrite recipe for adding a maven dependency to a specific pom.xml in multi modular project environment

Tags: openrewrite

I have few multi module projects where each modules has their own pom.xml , Also parent folder has pom.xml
Do we have recipe to add maven dependency in specified pom.xml only? Because If I simply apply OpenRewrite [adddependency](https://docs.openrewrite.org/recipes/maven/adddependency) recipe in project root folder then it adds dependency in each modules.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to implement your own recipe if there are conditional restrictions on when the recipe should be applied. You can still reuse parts of the existing AddDependency recipe or visitor, but the logic to decide when to apply should be up to you to implement. AddDependency is typically a building block that's only used with confidence from other recipes, and even then should be used with care when multi-module projects might come into play.

Comment: Can I get any custom recipe github URL for pom.xml as reference. it could help me to create own recipe.

Comment: Hi Manish; here is an example of a recipe that adds a conditional before calling out to AddDependency: https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-spring/blob/76013efcc065e4f4ca9b2a8ccdf9b5aca42d8629/src/main/java/org/openrewrite/java/spring/boot2/MigrateLocalServerPortAnnotation.java#L48